# How to commit version update of child modules in a multi-module maven project?

Tags: maven, maven-3, pom.xml, multi-module

In a multi-module maven project to set versions in parent pom we need to execute:

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=<version_to_set>
```

Then to update the version of the parent in the child modules we need to execute:

```
mvn -N versions:update-child-modules
```

The above two commands create files with name pom.xml.versionsBackup besides the original pom.xml. To commit the version update we need to execute:

```
mvn versions:commit
```

Which also deletes the pom.xml.versionsBackup file for the parent pom.xml, but not for the child modules.

How can we delete the pom.xml.versionsBackup files for the pom.xml of child modules?

Comment: `mvn versions:set` should also update the parent version mentioned in the child modules IIRC, so you don't need `versions:update-child-modules`. It seems `commit` doesn't work with all of the projects in the reactor yes, but you can not generate the backup files by setting [`generateBackupPoms`](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/set-mojo.html#generateBackupPoms) to false.

Comment: @Tunaki, in my case `mvn versions:set` is only updating the version of the super pom.xml, that's why I need to execute explicitly the `mvn versions:update-child-modules`. Probably for the same reason the `mvn versions:commit` is not removing the backup pom.xml. I know about the flag  `-DgenerateBackupPoms=false` but it backup is for safety purpose; if something goes wrong, `mvn versions:revert` would be useless.

Comment: Did you solve? - please leave an answer if so

Comment: You need to do the commit and revert from the project base module where it complies all the jars